# Can I have a memory mapped file, mapped to two or more processes at the same time (windows)?

Tags: windows, ipc, memory-mapped-files

I need to have two processes share information through a memory mapped file. One of them is going to only read to the file and the other is only going to write to it.
Is it OK for me just to leave the file always mapped to those two processes? I am currently:

1. mapping the file to the reader process
2. Writing
3. Unmapping the file
4. Mapping the file to the writer process
5. reading
6. Unmapping

And repeating over and over every time I need the processes to share information. My concern is that all these calls to map and unmap may be expensive. Should I keep the file mapped to both process al the time? I could regulate the access to the shared memory through mutexes.

What is the best way to do this kind of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to unmap the file after reading or writing at all. Windows guarantees that the data "visible" in the mapping in two processes will be the same when the local file is mapped on one computer.

Comment: Well, it's as synchronized as process-private data shared between threads is, which is to say that you need memory barriers and synchronization (locks or interlocked operations).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this repeatedly, then maintain the mapping.  Don't [prematurely optimize](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).  (If you do find there are problems, you can go back and fix them at that time.)

Comment: Thanks! Sound advice. I need to do this dozens of times per second... that's why I figured it was going to be bad. 
But you are right, I should not look at optimization just yet.

Comment: There will be no problems coming from not unmapping the file - MMFs were explicitly designed for this usage scenario.